# Generating JPA entities in microservices design

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, microservices

I am thinking of design and bit confused with generating entities in a microservices architecture (though I am new to microservices design, but I am fascinated with multiple lean war's). I have DB and multiple war's in mind. Should I generate the entities from DB and place them in a jar, and include the jar in every war i create, OR there is another option. Secondly where I place persistence.xml. And if i plan to use cache later to cache entity instances, will above approach pose any issues. Thanks

Comment: not sure I understand how microservices change you JPA entity design vs any other kind of application.  Are you talking about the entities themselves, or how to organize them and deal with the same entity being used in multiple microservices?

Comment: No my main concern is with packaging of entities.  Should I package entities in a jar and include in every war. Or a war should only include concerned entities.

Comment: you should probably restate your question with a description of what problem you're intending to solve.  How many services, how many entities, and what's the relationship between services and entities?

Comment: I don't know if it make any difference.  If I say 10 entities and 5 services.

Comment: Allright I believe we need to have decentralized data management for microservices. But to me it seems overkill, I will create 5 services and my database has 10 tables. Why break a small schema into multiple schemas. Is it good to create 5 schemas with 2 tables in each schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all microservices share the same database then it is not possible to move microservices to another host, it  breaks the principle of minimal data sharing, it increases dependency, and so on.
Centralised data storage is operationally convenient but microservices should wish to embed all its dependencies in order to achieve independently deployable. Alternate approach is: each microservice embedded all its dependencies including database so moving this microservice to anywhere would be trivial, which is beautiful but not practical in current context.

Microservices should own its tables because sharing tables between Microservices will kill mobility; but, sharing database cluster installation is absolutely ok (Nadareishvili, Mitra, McLarty, & Amundsen, 2016).  I found this approach to be best: Microservices owning independent schema within same database if database is Oracle or SQL Server.  If database is MySQL then micro services should own independent databases since I believe MySQL only supports one schema per database.

Microservices can own not only different database but also different type of database such as in my current application we are using MySQL for online transaction processing but using NoSQL for offline processing.

Using Spring Boot and Spring Data JPA I don't face any issues with generating entities in each microservice. I am still duplicating entity code in microservices but it is only for the required entities.  We can always create a common jar and share between microservices but it is not suitable in all situations. 
Similar discussion is in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47647560/how-to-share-entity-between-rest-service-between-two-microservices)